# sybase wired output after case when

Tags: sql, sybase

After this select to a sybase DB

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN CONVERT(datetime,getdate(),23)
    WHEN 'a' <> 'b' THEN ''
END
```

the output is always a date (tried in Squirrel and Aqua Data Studio).

This is always null

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN CONVERT(datetime,getdate(),23)
END
```

How can I get '' as result in case something is not true and a date calculation if something is true ?
Can someone explain that behavior ?

Comment: what are datatypes of column you are comparing for true and false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are seeing this behaviour because your two cases are returning different datatypes.

```
    SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN CONVERT(datetime,getdate(),23)  <-- returns datetime
    WHEN 'a' <> 'b' THEN ''                             <-- returns string
END
```

A select needs to return a consistent datatype. I guess that you want to return a string representation of the date. If this is the case then you can change your query to something like this:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),23)
    WHEN 'a' <> 'b' THEN ''
END
```

With this query I am seeing the correct responses for the case when.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, yes that's explains it. I'll see how I can get once a nicly formated date and once a nice string..at the end that ends up in a csv so string formating will be the way..Thanks !